# Given a discrete time Markov chain with three states $\{1,2,3\}$ and the transition matrix given:

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Let $$A=(a_{ij})_{3 \times 3}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 
\end{pmatrix}_{3 \times 3}$$

where $a_{ij}=Pr\{X_t+1=j | X_t=i\}$ where $X_t$ is  the state of the Markov chain at Time $t$

$a)$ show that the matrix chain is ergodic

$b)$ compute the stationary probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3$ for states $\{1,2,3\}$

$c)$ if the associated process starts at state $1$, derive a formula for the expectation of the time $T_3$ when the state $3$ appears for the first time

I have read the theoretical parts multiple times from different sources but I cannot grasp the idea of getting around this exercise. 
I would really appreciate an explanation of any of the $3$ points above as well as hints on how to proceed with them.

Comment: In order to avoid down-votes and botes to close your question, I suggest you 'take the tour', learn Math JaX for formatting, and follow the guidelines for questions here. Those include showing what you have tried and where you need help.

Comment: @nmasanta. Thanks for (really nice) formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to get you started with (a) and (b):

**(a)** A chain is ergodic if some power of its transition
matrix has all positive elements. For your chain, the
second power has all positive elements.

```
A = matrix(c(0.5, 0.5,   0,
             0.5,   0, 0.5,
               0, 0.5, 0.5), nrow = 3, byrow=T)
A 
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.5  0.5  0.0
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.5
[3,]  0.0  0.5  0.5

A2 = A %*% A;  A2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
[2,] 0.25 0.50 0.25
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.50
```

**(b)** You have not shown any work, so I have no context
to guess what you know and what method you are expected to use. Three possible approaches:

(i) Notice that the transition matrix is doubly-stochastic (columns as well as rows sum to unity).
Thus because the chain is irreducible and ergodic, the stationary distribution is uniform on the three states.

(ii) If a vector $\sigma$ has $\sigma A = \sigma$
then $\sigma$ is a stationary distribution of the
chain (and hence also the limiting distribution).
Here $\sigma = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3).$ This can be found
by solving three equations in three unknowns.

(iii) In general, $\sigma$ is proportional to the
left eigenvector of smallest modulus. So it can
be obtained in R (which uses right eigenvectors, hence the transpose `t(A)`) as:

```
g = eigen(t(A))
sg = as.numeric(g$vec[,1])
  # 1st col of vector output is vector you want
  # 'as.numeric' gets rid of complex-nr notation
sg = sg/sum(sg)  # scale so elements add to 1
sg
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
sg %*% A  # check
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

(a) Show that the chain is irreducible (this is easy) and that the chain is positive recurrent by finding a stationary distribution. Show that the period is $1$ (by irreducibility you have to check this for one state).

(b) Already done when you solved (a) using the suggested approach.

(c) The chain is positive recurrent, thus $E_3[T_3]$ is equal to $1/p_3$.

Comment: (+1) for approach to (c).

Comment: I think c) is about finding $\operatorname{E}_1(T_3)$. I don't see how you got $1/p_3$ for $\operatorname{E}_3(T_3)$. If we start in state $3$ and want the first positive hitting time, then $\operatorname{E}_3(T_3) = 1/2 + \operatorname{E}_2(T_3)/2 = 3/2$.

Comment: You are right, the question asks for $E_1(T_3)$. I misread. But $E_3(T_3)$ is definitely equal to $1/p_3$. It is well known that a positive recurrent chain has stationary distribution $\pi$ defined by $\pi(x) = 1/E_x(T_x)$

Comment: Right, sorry, $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ denotes the stationary distribution, so of course $\operatorname{E}_3(T_3) = 1/p_3$. And what I wrote should have been $\operatorname{E}_3(T_3) = 1/2 + (\operatorname{E}_2(T_3) + 1)/2$ anyway, and $\operatorname{E}_2(T_3)$ is $4$, not $2$. Gosh.